# Distorted rendering for electron based flatpak apps when they have access to dri

Tags: fedora, flatpak, amdgpu

When running Spotify or Slack via flatpak on Fedora 36 with XFCE I get the distortion like this: [image: img]

When I disable access to dri however both work fine and I see no distortion. I disabled dri using flatseal and that creates the following overrides:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/flatpak/overrides/com.slack.Slack 
[Context]
devices=!all
$ cat ~/.local/share/flatpak/overrides/com.spotify.Client
[Context]
devices=!dri
```

When I install slack via the rpm (found [here](https://slack.com/downloads/instructions/fedora)) it works fine also.

Info about my computer can be found here: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=778f7340fa

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it? I would be fine with disabling dri, but as slack needs access to webcam and audio I would prefer to not have an `devices=!all` override for it.

Comment: Another workaround seems to be to run `flatpak remove org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default` - however updating adds this back. This seems to be caused by [Mesa org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default 21.3.8 causes GUI display errors](https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/freedesktop-sdk/-/issues/1460).